# Run command on slave shutdown

Tags: jenkins, slave

Is it possible to run a command when Jenkins wants to shut down a SSH slave? My use case is shutting down the (physical) machine after Jenkins is done.

Comment: Have no idea what are you asking. Please add more details

Comment: What do you mean "Jenkins wants to shut down a SSH slave"?

Comment: When using SSH slaves there is an option that Jenkins disconnects from the slave if no builds have been pending for X minutes. "Take this agent online when in demand, offline when idle". I want to run some commands when that happens so that I can actually shut the machine down.